# Error when trying to attach an used address of shared-memory

Tags: c, linux, unix, shared-memory

Receiving the message "Invalid argument" when using shmget with the second parameter not being NULL.

It compiles ok, but when executing, I get this error message.

I've been stuck on this all day long.  Hope you can help me! :)

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>        
#include <sys/shm.h>        
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <stdio.h>          


int main()
{
    int idSharedMem;
    int *varSharedMem1;
    int *varSharedMem2;

    /* Create the shared memory */
    idSharedMem = shmget((key_t) 0001, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    if (idSharedMem == -1)
    {
        perror("shmget");
    }

    /* Allocate a memory address and attached it to a variable */
    varSharedMem1 = shmat(idSharedMem, NULL, 0);

    if (varSharedMem1 == (int *) -1)
    {
        perror("shmat1");
    }

    /* Sign a value to the variable */
    *varSharedMem1 = 5;

    /* Attach an existing allocated memory to another variable */
    varSharedMem2 = shmat(idSharedMem, varSharedMem1, 0);

    if (varSharedMem2 == (int *) -1)
    {
        /* PRINTS "shmat2: Invalid argument" */
        perror("shmat2");
    }

    /* Wanted it to print 5 */
    printf("Recovered value %d\n", *varSharedMem2);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You didn't state which function is giving you the error. If `shmget` -- what is the value of 'SHMMIN' on your platform? If it's less than `sizeof(int)`, this is documented and expected behavior.

Comment: Can you explain what the second call to `shmat` was supposed to do? The code doesn't make any sense, at least to me. And I can't figure out what its purpose is supposed to be. If you're trying to map the same segment again, why are you passing in `varSharedMem1`? There are a few things you could be trying to do. One is best done by `varSharedMem2=varSharedMem1;`. The other is best done by passing `NULL` as the second parameter. As is, I can't figure out what you are expecting to accomplish with that call.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 
`echo $SHMMIN` returns blank :( 
Am I doing it right? I'm newbie to unix.

I know I can simply assign one pointer to another, but I have to do it by using the second parameter. This is what the second parameter is supoesed to do right? 
At least it's what I've understood from manual.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Are you doing **what** right? I have no idea what you're trying to do. From what I can tell, it appears you are trying to create a second mapping right on top of the first mapping, but that makes no sense. If that's what you're trying to do, just don't do it -- it's already mapped. If you're trying to do something else, please explain what that something else *is*!

Comment: Thanks, David! It's what you told, but I could just understand well it on @nos post. The right thing I was wasking if i've done right was echoing the SHMMIN system variable :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `shmat(idSharedMem, varSharedMem1, 0);` you're trying to attach the segment at the location of `varSharedMem1`. However you have previously attached a segment at that location which will result in EINVAL. Linux provides a SHM_REMAP flag you can use to replace previously mapped segments.

shmat manpage:

> The (Linux-specific) SHM_REMAP flag may be specified in shmflg to
>   indicate that the mapping of the segment should replace any existing
>   mapping in the range starting at shmaddr and continuing for
>          the size of the segment.  (Normally an EINVAL error would result if a mapping already exists in this address range.)  In this
>   case, shmaddr must not be NULL.

Comment: Hmm! Thanks nos! 
I was working like if the second paramter was an used memory address, it would return me the same address I've passed to it, like the function was confirming that that address can be used.

But from what you've told, I can infer that I just need to pass the second parameter if I want to specify the new variable address, and it'll only work if it's not already used.

Thanks :D

Comment: What was strange to me was the message _Invalid argument_. It was looking like was a wrong variable type :/

Comment: Some reference, for those who will get here:
[link](http://anoncvs.postgresql.org/cvsweb.cgi/pgsql/src/backend/port/sysv_shmem.c?rev=1.55)

Answer (score 1):

From shmat man page:

```
If shmaddr isn't NULL and SHM_RND is specified in shmflg, the attach occurs at the
address equal to shmaddr rounded  down  to  the nearest multiple of SHMLBA. 
Otherwise shmaddr must be a page-aligned address at which the attach occurs.
```

more from shmat man page:

```
Using shmat() with shmaddr equal to NULL is the preferred, portable way of 
attaching a shared memory segment.
```

To make a second attach, just:

```
varSharedMem2 = shmat(idSharedMem, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, Pepe! But I've already read the man page a dozen times, I really want to do it passing the second parameter not null.

Comment: @marcioggs you can do this but you must ensure your second parameter is page aligned

Comment: Anyway this second attach would try to get a free memory address, but this wouldn't be possible, since the shared-memory that has been created just hold enough space for a single int.

Comment: What do you mean by page aligned? Gonna Google for it.

Comment: Read this [link](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13381) and `posix_memalign`man page

Comment: @marcioggs You have already attached the segment at the memory location of varSharedMem1(which is why it fails the 2. time) , why do you need to attach it at the same location again ?

Comment: I've thought of attached as "bringing the memory adress to the process", but it works more like "signing it to any process use"

Comment: @marcioggs You have a shared memory segment. shmat(xxx,NULL,0) will attach that segment at an a suitable address in your process and return the address that the system chose. shmat(xxx,varSharedMem1,0) will try to attach that segment to the address in your process stored by the varSharedMem1 pointer.

Comment: @nos It's was already very clear to me the way shmat works from your first post :) Thanks for this detailed explanation. Saved my day!